# loop decrements at run time Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, cell

I'm working with cell arrays in a for-loop, However I want to delete a cell at run time at specified condition, and wants the rest of loop iterations to be stable. As when delete any cell from cell arrays the loop condition should be reformatted as the iterations are changed. Any suggestions/possibilities ?

**Error:**

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in myCode (line 33)
         if (CellArray2{jj}(ii,:) ~= 0)
```

**My Code:**

```
while ii<=1000
for jj=1:10
if (CellArray2{jj}(ii,:) ~= 0)
CellArray1(jj) = [];
CellArray2(jj) = [];
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to delete elements from a array while indexing over it, is indexing backwards:

```
for index=numel(MyArray):-1:1
  if (condition)
    MyArray(index)=[]
  end
end
```

In case you can't iterate backwards in your case, keep track of the elements you want to delete and delete all at once:

```
toDelete=false(size(MyArray))
for index=1:numel(MyArray)
  if (condition)
    toDelete(index)=true
  end
end
%deletes everything afterwards, using logical indexing
MyArray(toDelete)=[]
```

I assume the second solution to be faster, because data has only to be shifted once, but I did not test it.

Comment: I want to delete particular index of cell array not all at once.

Comment: And also its not to delete last or first cell, any cell in cell array. Actually I want to refresh the loop according to new size.

Comment: The code does not delete all elements, unless "condition" is always true.